# Import XML file in R without opening tag

Tags: r, xml

I'm making a script in R that downloads, extracts the data straight from a web address and imports it into R automatically. The problem is that the file imported in XML format does not contain the opening tag. Is it possible to open an XML file without the opening tag or automatically, with R, include an opening tag before importing the file in R, without doing this manually? The file I'm trying to import is '20220207_Pedidos_xml_2015.xml' available in https://dadosabertos-download.cgu.gov.br/FalaBR/Arquivos_FalaBR_Filtrado/Arquivos_xml_2015.zip

```
library(XML)
txt = readLines("F:/Meu repositório/logo dail/20220206_Pedidos_xml_2015.xml", encoding = 'UTF-16LE')
xml = xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

Error:

```
> xml = xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
Start tag expected, '<' not found
Error: 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Comment: Warning for other readers: this is a very large download: one of the files is 1.6Gb.

Answer (score 0):

The file you identified looks perfectly well-formed to me. Oxygen opens it without complaint (except for warnings saying do you really want to open such a large XML file).

I suspect you've misdiagnosed the problem. For example, are you sure the encoding is UTF-16LE (I haven't checked).

Comment: Yes, the encoding is UTF-16LE. I tried with other packages in R itself, but the error persists.

`library(xml2) 
df <- read_xml('F:/Meu repositório/logo dail/20220206_Pedidos_xml_2015.xml', encoding = 'UTF-16LE')`

Comment: I suggest you try it with some tool outside of R, which will help by eliminating possible causes of the problem.